# Does the vue 3 app with Azure AD authentication need configuration change while deploying as static web app in Azure Storage?

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, vuejs3, azure-ad-msal

In our vue 3 application, i have implemented Azure AD authentication using msal.js. For this, i have added the configurations as mentioned/followed in official documentation and registered the app in Azure AD.

Now, i have to deploy this application as static web app in Azure storage. Does any impact in our implementation for AAD authentication? Is there any configuration change after deployment?

I am new to this Azure environment. Maybe it is a lame question to ask but need some information about this. If configuration changes then can anyone give any documents or samples to understand it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to check and configure few things while deploying Vue3 App.

I have taken references from the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal).

- Navigate to the `Storage Account` => select `Static website` under `Data management`,
  Enable the `Static website`.

[image]

- Also configure the `CORS` rule.
  [image]
- Make sure to add the Storage Account endpoint in the `Redirect URI` of the Registered App.

> Does any impact in our implementation for AAD authentication? Is there any configuration change after deployment?

AFAIK, there will be no impact in the authentication after the deployment if the configurations are set correctly.